# Show and hide html elements depending on radio selection

Tags: html, jquery

Yes, there are many posts that are kind of similar but not like mine I guess. After struggling for a while I'm not able to come up with a solution. I need help!

I have 4 different criteria:

**Resident/Single, Resident/Family, Non-Resident/Single, Non-Resident/Family**

For example: if **Resident** and **Single** are checked then show that div. The rest goes the same way.

```
<fieldset>
  <ol id="membership">
   <li>
    <input type="radio" name="resident" value="Resident" checked="checked" /> Resident
    <input type="radio" name="resident" value="Non-Resident"  /> Non-Resident
   </li>
   <li>
    <input type="radio" name="single" value="Single" checked="checked" /> Single
    <input type="radio" name="single" value="Family"  /> Family
   </li>
 </ol>

 <div style="display: none;">
  <div>Resident/Single</div>
  <div>Resident/Family</div>
  <div>Non-Resident/Single</div>
  <div>Non-Resident/Family</div>
 </div>

</fieldset>
```

This is as far as I was able to go.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($('input[value="Resident"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="Single"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    } else if ($('input[value="Resident"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="Family"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    } else if ($('input[value="Non-Resident"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="Single"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    } else if ($('input[value="Non-Resident"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="Family"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    } else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

This is my repl: https://repl.it/@labanino/Show-based-on-selection#script.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ifs statement` to show/hide divs you can simply get the `checked` values of radio button then just loop through your `divs` and compare if the `.text()` is equal to radio values show that divs only .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".category div:eq(0)").show() //show 1st div
  $('input').change(function() {
    //get radio values
    var value = $("input[name='resident']:checked").val();
    var value1 = $("input[name='single']:checked").val();
    console.log(value + "/" + value1)
    $(".category div").hide(); //hide all divs
    var divss = value + "/" + value1;
    //loop through divs
    $(".category div").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() === divss) {
        $(this).show() //show that div
      }
    })
  });

})
```

```css
 .category > div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <ol id="membership">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="resident" value="Resident" checked="checked" /> Resident
      <input type="radio" name="resident" value="Non-Resident" /> Non-Resident
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="single" value="Single" checked="checked" /> Single
      <input type="radio" name="single" value="Family" /> Family
    </li>
  </ol>

  <div class="category">
    <div>Resident/Single</div>
    <div>Resident/Family</div>
    <div>Non-Resident/Single</div>
    <div>Non-Resident/Family</div>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to check the value, the text in the divs are only placeholders. Something else would go in there. Thanks.

Comment: How about using custom html attribute  instead of `.text()`  then you just need to check `.attr("someattribute")`?

Comment: Now if you change the text in the divs it breaks. I just want to be able to show the content inside the divs based on the previous selection. The content in the divs can be anything, even a form. Thanks, Swati

Comment: Hi, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLv1qr53/) .What i did was content of div can be anything only i have added `data-*` attribute to easily find the div you need to show .

Comment: Beautiful Swati! I even put a little form in one of the divs and worked perfectly. Thank you so very much for your patient.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the divs by name or value and show them while hiding the others.
Check this repl -
https://repl.it/@DavidThomas12/Show-based-on-selection

I believe it fits your use case.